# Keep Logo in Middle of Page when Resizing Page

Tags: html, css

I have solutions that work in all browsers except IE, so I'd appreciate if the answers worked in IE.

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="redBar"></div>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/header.gif" id="logo1">
            </div>

            <div id="explanation">
                Next div.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
```

I guess I'll just give the CSS too:

```
    #main
{
    padding-left:229px;
    padding-right:229px;
}



#logo1
{
    width:auto;
    z-index:1;
    position: relative;
    left:250px;
}

#main
{
    //background-image:url('../images/indexBack.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-xy;
    width:980px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: middle or center of page? (horizontal and vertical or just horizontal)

Comment: horizontal and vertical if possible

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. A quick picture would probably help.

Comment: I guess I misspoke; I need the logo at the top of the page in the middle.

Comment: I guess if I could center the container div that would work too. It has a width of 980px so it'll be smaller than the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you're trying to do is relatively simple but you're putting your logo nested in a few block elements that might mess it up because they don't have the necessary styling applied to them...

A visual image of the different areas would help but heres what I think you're trying to do. I am asuming you want the entire page centered too (if not then it is impossible with your current html).

(Also you defined the css class for #main twice)

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="redBar"></div>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/header.gif" />
        </div>

        <div id="explanation">
            Next div.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</div>

<style>

#main
{
    background-image:url('../images/indexBack.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-xy;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header img /* don't put un-needed ids on elements */
{
    display:block; /* img is an inline element by default but we want it as a block so margin works */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much. I would vote you up but I can't.

Comment: Register and just contribute a little ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the dimensions of the logo then you can use absolute positioning.  Lets say your logo is 200x100:

```
#logo1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;   /*  half the logo height  */
    margin-left:-100px; /*  half the logo width   */
}
```

This does rather assume that your element's container fills the size of the screen too though.